# Unit testing something with ObserveOnDispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, system.reactive, dispatcher

I've some code in my view model as follows:

```
miService.GetSomething(par1, par2)
.ObserveOnDispatcher()
.Subscribe(dt =>
 {
    DoSomething(dt);
 });
```

Then in my test, I'm "mocking" my service as follows:

```
miService.Setup(ms => ms.GetSomething(....))
.Returns(Observable.Return(XYZ));
```

The problem is that due to the ObserveOnDispatcher, the subscribe delegate is never executed.

I've seen some code with DispatcherFrame and PushFrame, but the problem is that I don't know "where", I can call

```
frame.Continue = false;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.Background, 
  new Action(() => frame.Continue = false));
Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
```

Comment: Sorry but this code doesn't even compile.

if i change to :

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new DispatcherOperationCallback(o =>
             {
              frame.Continue = false;
              return null; // or return null;
             }));

I get the following exception:
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch.

Comment: Sorry - should have tried to compile my code first. Try the updated version.